# Getting 'Uncaught' after catching error in firebase.auth() with async

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

```
async login({ commit }, { email, password }) {
  let result
  try {
    result = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    commit('setUser', result.user)
  } catch (err) {
    commit('setError', err)
  }
}
```

This is an action in Vuex. When this runs, I expect the `commit('seteError', err)` to be a valid error handler for the error returned from `catch (err)`. Instead, I get an 'Uncaught' exception and execution stops.

Would appreciate any insights from anyone who managed to use `async` with `firebase.auth()`

Comment: Please include your Exception/Error as a Code Sample (`{}`) in your Question. Is the Exception really just `'Uncaught'`?

Comment: Indeed, that's the whole message: Uncaught K {__ob__: Observer}. Here K is the error object returned by `err`, which I'm passing to `commit`

Comment: I have the same issue.  `Uncaught L {code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly formatted."}`. Cesar, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `Uncaught Bg {code: "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential", message: "An account already exists with the same email addr…ng a provider associated with this email address.", email: "XXXXXX", credential: Vf}`. I am catching the error and can log it, but it still shows up as uncaught...

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue today - it appears to be due to the implementation of the Closure promise library that firebase auth uses. There is a closed issue in the firebase-js-sdk project [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1881) with some details on it. Ultimately, what is happening with this implantation is a timeout is getting set that throws an exception outside of the scope of the `try/catch`:

[image]

To avoid this, the exception needs to be handled by calling `.catch()` on the returned promise e.g.:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .catch((ex) => { /* handle exception */ });
```

As I have all of my firebase logic wrapped and centralized, what I ended up doing is wrapping the firebase Promise in one of my own:

```
export async function signIn(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCreds) => resolve(userCreds))
      .catch((reason) => reject(reason));
  });
}
```

The wrapper function can then be called using async await:

```
try {
  const result = await signIn(email, password)
  // Do what you need to with the result
} catch (ex) {
  // Handle any exceptions
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I managed to handle firebase authentication with async in Vuex. I needed to use `onAuthStateChanged`

```
async login({ commit, dispatch }, { email, password }) {
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    await dispatch('session')
  } catch (err) {
    commit('setError', err)
  }
}
```

Where the 'session' dispatch simply does:

```
async session({ commit }) {
  let user
  try {
    user = await userInSession()
    commit('setUser', user)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    commit('setUser', {})
  }
}
```

and the userInSession function uses `onAuthStateChanged`:

```
const userInSession =  function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        resolve(user.uid)
      } else {
        reject(Error('No user authenticated'))
      }
    })
  })
}
```